# If checkbox is checked in datagrid in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

On form2 in a datagrid field, I have "admin" which is a checkbox. When I call form2 from form1
I want it first to check if THIS user (which is logged in) has checked in field "admin".
If yes, grant the user access to form2, else return to form1 with a message box explaining that the user doesn't have access.

Should the check "if has checked" be on form2 load?

EDIT: Can it be done like:

```
form1:
  call form2 function test

form2:
    function test that checks if the current user has checked the checkbox in the datagrid
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand to what your asking, there are various ways you can do that. You could check on the load event of form2 if user has admin access, or you could perform the check from form1 and check if user has admin access before creating an instance of form2.

Comment: In short, should be on form2. Problem is i can not check if checkbox is checked on load because datagrid is being filled in the same time. So it should come after that, but still should not show that form(form2) if THIS user(logged one) has no admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. First, read the state from DataGrid to a CheckBox like:

```
CheckBox.Checked = GridView.Rows[0].Cells[Index.Of.CheckBox]
```

Or you should TypeCast:

```
if ((CheckBox)GridView.Rows[0].Cells[Index.Of.CheckBox]).Checked)
    DoWhatEverYouWant
```

Answer (score 0):

No, if you perform the check in Load, then you will probably have trouble preventing the form from appearing.

Instead, put method on Form1 that will perform the check or show Form2?  This way all your code which would want to display Form2 can benefit from the same check.

```
public class Form1
{
   ...
   public void ShowAdminForm2()
   {
      if (!chkAdmin.IsChecked)
         MessageBox.Show ("Not admin");
      else
         new Form2().ShowDialog();
   }
}
```

Comment: That was my first idea. On form1 to have button that will on click direct you to form2. problem is when i want to compare if admin field is checked for current user i get error. First you can't go "if (!chkAdmin.IsChecked)", instead you have to check in datagrid, second that datagrid is on form2 and will not allow you to look at it.

Comment: Usually, it is better interpret the data from the database first.  Can you get a canonical form of your data and then check for the permission in data, rather than waiting for the control to be loaded?